# Stopping MySQL Server from command line on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, command-line, command-prompt

I am trying to shutdown the mysql server from command line.

MySQL root password is "" (blank)

```
C:\Users\Jigar>"C:\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe" -u root -p shutdown
Enter password:
```

When I just press enter, it stops the server.

But when I don't specify `-p`, I am not able to stop the server:

```
C:\Users\Jigar>"C:\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe" -u root shutdown
C:\mysql\bin\mysqladmin.exe: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

I am actually writing a program to stop the server. In mac I was able to stop the server with blank root password without specifying `-p` in the command. But I am not able to do the same in Windows.

Comment: Try using `--password` to set a blank one (I'm not sure if that will work).

Comment: Having a blank root password is not ideal from a security standpoint.

Comment: @Vatev, same result as `-p`. @Acyclic Tau, Agree. But some people leave it blank on development machine.